# Complete Removal of Webstorm from Ubuntu

Tags: ide

I installed Webstorm and something went wrong so I removed the installation folder and every thing using the advice from [here](https://gist.github.com/denji/9731967).

A run of `whereis` turns up nothing, but when I try to install a fresh Webstorm it simply launches the formerly installed one and I don't know where that installation is coming from.

How can I completely remove all traces of Webstorm and install it fresh?

Comment: What commands did you run exactly ? There are a bunch of commands at the bottom of the page as well.

Comment: I ran this comprehensive command                                                                      `curl -sL https://gist.github.com/denji/9731967/raw/jetbrains-uninstall.sh | bash -s` , after physically removing the **.webstorm** directory from my **home directory**.

Comment: As IO said, there are a bunch of commands in the comments on that page in addition to the script.

Comment: How did you install Webstorm?

Comment: @David I followed the instruction on the JetBrains website

Comment: Can you please cite them or provide a link to them? Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. It's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: Download it here: [https://www.jetbrains.com/](https://www.jetbrains.com/)                                                                         Unpack the WebStorm-11.0.2.tar.gz file using the following command: tar xfz WebStorm-11.0.2.tar.gz
Run WebStorm.sh from the bin subdirectory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been running the fresh install using **sudo** rights but this time I ran it without the **sudo** rights and was able to install it fresh. Here instead of `sudo ./webstorm.sh`, I used `./webstorm.sh`.